# Show that if f is real-valued function that is Riemann Integrable on [a,b] then following holds:

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if f is  real-valued function that is Riemann Integrable on [a,b] then $\exists$ c $\in$ [a,b] such that  $\int_{a}^{c}{f dx}$ =  $\int_{c}^{b}{f dx}$.

**My attempt**

Let us assume that $\int_{a}^{c}{f dx}$ $\neq$  $\int_{c}^{b}{f dx}$ for all c $\in$ [a,b] then WLOG, $\int_{a}^{c}{f dx}$ $>$  $\int_{c}^{b}{f dx}$. Then putting c=a gives that $\int_{a}^{a}{f dx}$ $>$  $\int_{a}^{b}{f dx}$ i.e $\int_{a}^{b}{f dx}$ $<$ 0.

On the other hand, putting c=b gives $\int_{a}^{b}{f dx}$ $>$  $\int_{b}^{b}{f dx}$ i.e. $\int_{a}^{b}{f dx}$ $> $ 0. Contradiction.

What is problem with my work, if any.

Comment: Isn't there any assumption about signs? Because either I misunderstood something , or the next is a counterexample: for any $\;c\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\,\frac\pi2\right)\;$ we have
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^c\sin x\;dx=-\cos c\;,\;\;\int_c^{\pi/2}\sin x\;dx=\cos c$$so if the claim was true in this case we'd have that there exists $\;c\in(-\pi/2\,,\,\,\pi/2)\;$ with $\;-\cos c=\cos c\;$ , which of course is impossible as $\;\cos x\;$ is even and nonzero on the open interval $\;(-\pi/2\,,\,\,\pi/2)\;$

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt re-written in a way to use directly the intermediate value theorem:
$$g(x)=\int_{a}^{x}{f dx}-\int_{x}^{b}{f dx}, \ \ \ x\in [a,b]$$
Obviously $g$ has different signs at the ends (if equals $0$, then pick c to be either endpoint.)

Comment: To apply IVT, we need the fact that g(x) is continuous. How do we obtain that?

Comment: Use boundedness of $ f $ and the monotonicity of the integral?

Comment: I just added a notice, which may not be showing at the moment. Fact: If $f$ is bounded then the integral is continuous.

Comment: @Behnam it has to be. Since the condition is Riemann integrability.

Comment: So what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: @HumbleStudent: There is nothing wrong with your approach but it does mention things in an obvious manner but in reality those things are not obvious and require a proof. Thus if $\int_{a}^{c} f \neq \int_{c}^{b}f$ for all $c \in [a, b]$ then how do you conclude that $\int_{a}^{c}f > \int_{c}^{b}f$ for all $c$? This is true but can be concluded only if the function $\int_{a}^{x}f$ is continuous. It is continuous but at least you need to mention this fact.

Answer (score 0):

The missing step in your answer is the implication that $$∫_{a}^{c}fdx ≠ ∫_c^bfdx $$ means that for *ALL* $ c ∈ [a,b] $ , $ ∫_{a}^{c}fdx > ∫_c^bfdx $.

In fact by claiming this, you're almost claiming the thing you want to prove!
In other words, this claim is equivalent to your final assertion.